# I receive error after reboot page in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vite

Delab some code changes `Vue3-Vite`.
I receive error after reboot page in Vue3.

*Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'router' before initialization*

`router\index.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
]
```

`App.vue`

```js
<router-link
            to="/"
        >
          <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-4"
          >
            Home
          </button>
        </router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

router\index.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
const history = createWebHistory();
const routes = [/* Routes*/];
const router = createRouter({ history, routes });
export default router;
```

add router in main.js

```
import router from "./router";
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

At no time does it see how you use a router in your app when it is mounted.
In all cases you should do something like

```
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
    import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
```

> ```
>    import {   createApp} from 'vue';
>  
>      
>      const routes = createRouter([
>         {
>              path: '/',
>              name: 'Home',
>             component: Home
>          },
>      )]
>
>  const app = createApp(Home);
>  app.use(routes);
> ```